# Safari on iPad - Incorrect handling of HTTP status code 204

Tags: asp.net, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, safari, http-status-codes

We are rendering an ASP.Net web form with a runat="server" tag in a bootstrap modal. We use the built in bootstrap capability to use the jQuery load function perform a get request and then insert the response into the bootstrap modal markup.

The asp.net web form returns a HTTP Status Code of 204 (no content) on postback this means we can submit the form, the ASP.Net server side click event fires appropriately and the browser does not attempt to render the response. We then close the bootstrap modal with some javascript.

This works beautifully on windows in IE10, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. On the iPad however in Safari responds to the 204 status code by rendering the original page markup displayed as text. I have also tried 302 Not Modified, which didn't resolve the problem either (and is not really semantically correct).

I have searched for similar problems and only found a reference to an old webkit bug from 2008 where the code was described as rendering a blank page when receiving a 204.

**Work Around**

I have also tried setting SuppressContent property of the Response object to true:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Do page rendering stuff
}
else
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
    Response.SuppressContent = true;
}
```

This does help in that Safari no longer renders the original page markup as text, the bootstrap modal is closed via the javascript call but safari displays the URL for the page that was loaded in the modal in the address bar and behaves like it's loading a page but never does. The user can use the application and request other pages no problems, so we can consider this is a work around. However, I would like to find something cleaner.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**Note**: We are refactoring the UI of a legacy web app and are unable to completely change the manner in which the pages operate.